# Plotting CDF of the values in a raster (.tif) file, using Python or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, osgeo

I have a tiff file with some values and I want to read those values and plot a CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function). So far I only know how to get the mean value

```
from osgeo import gdal
gtif = gdal.Open( "INPUT.tif" )
srcband = gtif.GetRasterBand(band)
stats = srcband.GetStatistics( True, True )
mean_value = stats[2]
```

I prefer using Python but if QGIS already has a CDF feature implemented I can also use it.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788200/calculate-the-cumulative-distribution-function-cdf-in-python) on SO. You would have to read your raster as a NumPy array, mask out the NoData values and then follow the steps presented there.